# Loss of precision when dividing doubles in swift

Tags: swift

I try to find the steps between a min and a max value with a given step-size, using swift 2.1.

So we have a min and a max value, both of type Double. The step-size is a Double too. If min is 0.0 and max 0.5 with steps of 0.1, the result is 6, obviously.

But if I start with -0.1 as the minimum value, the result is 6 too. But should be 7, agree?

Here is my Playground example:

```
let min:Double = -0.1
let max:Double = 0.5

let step:Double = 0.1

var steps: Int {
    return Int((max - min) / step) + 1
}

print("steps: \(steps)") // returns "steps: 6", but should be 7
```

The result is 6.99999999 if we use a Double for the steps variable. But this loss of precision only occurs when our min value is negative.

Do you know a workaround? I just don't want to `round()` each time I calculate with Doubles.

Comment: That's just how doubles work, you'll never ever get away from rounding issues if working in doubles. Do you actually need to use doubles with your real world data, though? If you can get away with it, it's sometimes better to work in integers and format them for display.

Comment: A workaround is to use `Float`

Comment: @JonStory The value min, max and step could be any number without limitation, so I can't use integers.I'm just wondering the fact that if I define 0.1 as a double, it is exactly 0.1, but if I set one of this two values to -0.1, it will be interpreted as -0.099999999.

Comment: Yup, that's just how it works unfortunately. Even more annoyingly, it won't always be the same values on every system. This is just how double's work because we're "squeezing" more numbers into a smaller storage space, it's impossible not to lose some accuracy

Comment: @vadian - floating point has the exact same problem, although it tends to happen slightly less often

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use `Int()` it forces truncation of your number, which always rounds towards zero. So, 6.9999 becomes 6 rather than 7, because it's closer to zero. If you use `round()` first it should help:

```
var steps: Int {
    return Int(round((max - min) / step) + 1.0)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That's always not a good idea to calculate integral steps based on floating point ranges, you'll always encounter issues, and you won't be able to do much.

Instead I recommend to build your logic on integral steps, and calculate double values based on integral values (not vice versa as you do). I.e. you don't calculate integral step based on range, but you set your integral number of steps and calculate your double step.